# Active choice plugin Groovy script - Read environment variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, environment-variables

I want to use environment variable "WORKSPACE" in the active choice plugin groovy script.
I tried to retrieve it like this but it didnt work. WORKSPACE is not recognised.

${WORKSPACE}

Can anyone help me here?

Snippet:

```
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()

def proc ='/test/script.sh'.execute()

proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
println sout
```

Here instead of `/test/script.sh` i need to access the script as following:

```
def process='$workspace path/test/script.sh
```

Comment: please show the groovy script you written for active choice plugin.

Comment: Edited with the example  snippet

Comment: @yong - do  you have any idea on how to access workspace path in the above mentioned script ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get that "environment" variable. A better name would be "property". Those are dynamically generated by Jenkins when the **build starts**, not when the parameters are set.
You can get some environment variables with [EnvVars](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/EnvVars.html) when you're setting the parameters, but they are very few. This can be tested on the Jenkins Script Console with the following code:

```
import hudson.EnvVars

for (envVarName in EnvVars.masterEnvVars.keySet()) {
  def envVarValue = EnvVars.masterEnvVars[envVarName]
  println("${envVarName}=${envVarValue}")
}
```

Result:

```
_=/etc/alternatives/java
HOME=/home/jenkins
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LOGNAME=jenkins
NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
PWD=/
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=2
TERM=xterm-256color
USER=jenkins
XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
```

WORKSPACE property has more to it. The directory may not exist when you launch the build, specially if it's the first time you are doing it. My recommendation, if it makes sense to you, is to place the script in userContent directory and work out the rest based on that.